# autoComplete.js Uncaught (in promise) undefined and can't select autocomplete result on IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, autocomplete

I'm using the [autoComplete.Js](https://tarekraafat.github.io/autoComplete.js/#/) library for my project. But I need it to work on IE11.
I added the missing polyfills to make it work properly but I still get an issue.

Autocomplete results should disappear by clicking on it and fill in the input with the selected result (classic autocomplete behavior).

On IE11, clicking on a result doesn't do anything.

The library provides a way to handle "selection"

```
onSelection: feedback => {             // Action script onSelection event | (Optional)
        console.log(feedback.selection.value.image_url);
    }
```

I use it the same way but I got a console error on IE11:

```
Uncaught (in promise) undefined
```

I tried to comment the `onSelection` part, I don't get the error but still can't select any result.

Is there any workaround I'm missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the package browser support:

https://tarekraafat.github.io/autoComplete.js/#/?id=_4-browsers-support

They do not claim to support IE11. Try different library or ask them for support. maybe they know a way to solve it